# MySql: Где используются 4 и 5 нормальные формы?

Tags: mysql, sql

Дорогие знатоки, изучая MySql нормальные формы дошел до третьего. Все понял отлично. Но вот дальше чуть запутался. Можно ли на реальном примере показать их в действии.

К примеру

```
Table authors
id  name

Table books
id  title  price

Table authors_books
author_id  book_id
```

У авторов есть емейлы. Храню их в отдельной таблице. Но по моему это все таки относится к третьей нормальной форме.

```
Table author_emails
id  author_id  email
```

Пожалуйста приведите примеры с пояснениями .
Спасибо!

Comment: каждый автор может иметь несколько емейлов и количество емейлов не ограничено

Comment: @Egor По моему у автора вопроса стоит задача понять в каких случаях используется 4,5 нормальные формы.А иметь 4 таблицы это не значит 4 нормальная форма по моему

Comment: @Egor Мне кажется понятный вопрос, надо уже отвечать)))))))

Comment: Простите ребята и автор вопроса! Не правильно понял суть вопроса(

Comment: @Egor Все норм, а если будут интересные мысли готовы прочитать.

Comment: @Egor Все нормально :) это хороший и сложный вопрос

Comment: у Вас тут за счет такой структуры таблиц пятая НФ и получается

Comment: Нормальные формы от 4 и выше используются только в академической науке. На практике ограничиваются НФБК. Это связано с тем, что идеальная в алгебраическом смысле операция декомпозиции на практике (в реальных РСУБД) имеет стоимость и в скорости выборки и в стоимости сопровождения.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов ну, вообще-то любая денормализация также имеет свою стоимость, как бы не еще большую...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, нормализация и денормализация увеличивают стоимость одних операций, но уменьшают других. Мне иногда приходилось даже 1НФ нарушать, но только после исследования частоты всех операций, которые будут применяться.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если 1-3 НФ позволяют избавиться от избыточности неключевых атрибутов (избыточность в сложном первичном ключе просто игнорится), то 4 и 5 НФ позволяют избавиться от избыточности внутри первичного ключа.
Поэтому, чтобы искать от чего бы избавиться, чтобы привести таблицу к 4, а потом 5 НФ, первичный ключ должен состоять минимум из 3х атрибутов. В противном случае (ключ состоит из 1-2 атрибутов) таблица уже находится в 4 и 5 НФ.
Добавление полей id сильно мешает пониманию НФ.
Если бы вместо 
id  author_id  email
было что-то типа:
address_id author_id  email     - эти три атрибута и есть первичный ключ, таблица уже находится в 3НФ.

Тогда можно было бы выделить две многозначные зависимости: У автора может быть несколько физ.адресов и несколько электронных почт. Причем адрес и эл. почта между собой не связаны.
Избавляемся путем разделения на 2 таблицы: 
address_id author_id 
и
author_id  email

Эти таблицы находятся в 4НФ, т.к. в них отсутствуют многозначные зависимости.

Если каким-то загадочным образом существует зависимость между address_id и email, при условии, что и предыдущие условия выполняются (У автора может быть несколько физ.адресов и несколько электронных почт) тогда мы не можем назвать это многозначной зависимостью, а, следовательно, и избавляться для 4НФ не от чего, т.е. таблица address_id author_id email уже находится в 4НФ. Но, зато такое явление можем назвать зависимостью соединения - чего не должно быть в 5НФ. От зависимости соединения можем избавиться, разбив исходную табл. на три: address_id author_id, author_id emai, address_id email

Comment: Дополнение. Не только первичный ключ - а любой естественный ключ. Наличие атрибута id никоим образом не мешает остальным атрибутам формировать подобный ключ.

Comment: Не естественный, а потенциальный.

Comment: Естественным называют первичный ключ из информационных полей таблицы. id - это суррогатный первичный ключ.  Именно про потенциальные ключи (они само собой являются естественными) очень быстро забывают. Что впрочем не наказуемо.  И даже позволяет сразу приводить таблицу не к 3НФ, а к НФБК.   Наличие id очень сильно отвлекает человека от потребности анализировать таблицы на наличие избыточности в других атрибутах и это не только мое мнение. Поэтому я предлагаю на него вообще не обращать внимания при нормализации. Добавить его всегда успеете.

Comment: Просто ваша формулировка в первом предложении выглядит так, как будто добавление суррогатного ключа автоматически приводит таблицу к 5НФ. Чего, разумеется, не происходит.